# Can't find .NET assembly from SSRS 3.0 Reports

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, .net-assembly, reportbuilder3.0

I'm developing some reports in SSRS 3.0, and I've hit a snag. I've got a .NET method that I need to call, and I can't get it to work. I've found a few "how to" websites that purportedly explain the process, but I can't seem to make it work. As a first experiment, to just prove I can do this, I've written a little "HelloWorld" program that just returns two strings concatenated together with a space between:

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    public class Hello
    {
        public static string SayHello(string hello, string world)
        {
            return hello + " " + world;
        }
    }
}
```

I've got the reference defined in the Report Properties / References tab; but when I try to run it, I get

> Error while loading code module: ‘HelloWorld, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null’. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'HelloWorld, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I've copied the DLL to numerous suggested locations:

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin
- The folder with the RDL file

Nothing seems to work.

I've seen reference to editing the rssrvpolicy.config file; but my system doesn't have one. I could create it, but I don't know where to put it.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, Report Builder 3.0, and SQL Server CE (I have SQL Server installed on my dev machine as well; but it will not be on the target machines). We will not be using a Report Server -- the target machines are all standalone, and very few will have network access.

If there's any other information I can provide, please let me know. And thanks for any suggestions you may have.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a mixed DLLs CPU architecture issue.

How do you compile your DLLs (x64, x84 , AnyCPU)?

Try to match the DLLs to correct CPU architecture of the server. then clean solution and compile it with as debug or release (that doesn't matter).

Make sure to clean all copies of previous DLLs , before copying the new ones. (just to be on the safe side)

Let me know if that works for you...